# Logcat is often out of work

Tags: android, logcat

Logcat is often not working, showing nothing. It's very unlivable. Restarting eclipse everytime it happens is too annoying.
Is there anything I can do to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: You can run logcat from the command line, just run adb logcat. I often have better luck with that, especially if I am running multiple eclipse instances.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sometimes the Logcat is empty in Eclipse because the emulator doesn't have the focus. Go to the DDMS perspective and try clicking on the 'emulator' entry in the top-left screen.

Can be even more confusing if there's also a real G1 connected, then you have to choose from which one you want to see the output :)

Hope this helped.

Comment: This is what I usually do as well. I usually have to click on my Nexus One icon on the Devices tab in Eclipse for the Logcat window to refresh.

Comment: I always get logcat on track through selecting the device in DDMS AND/OR clicking on "V" (verbose) or another button in the logcat output

Answer (score 3):

I just always keep logcat open in my terminal instead of eclipse.  Just navigate to your platform-tools folder and type `adb logcat`

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse only has a limitted buffer to display the logcat. There's a little clear button somewhere on that page, I forget where. Press that, it will clear the logcat and start displaying again.

Answer (score 1):

Even `adb logcat` shows weird stuff and stops working after a while for no apparent reason: [logcat.png](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/6/logcat.png/).  Eclipse restart and Android device restart doesn't help.

however console: `adb logcat -c` does work.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens to me when I'm running both an avd in the emulator and usb debugging on a physical device. The avd will not give up focus, even though I'm loading the apk onto the device for debugging. I can fix by closing the avd.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you selected certain session filter by mistake. By showing the two-pane view of your LogCat you'll be able to check the active filter in the left-pane. I once fixed the empty LogCat by selecting "All messages".