# Eclipse LogCat is broken

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Quite often LogCat loose connection to a device or an emulator and became broken for the time of Eclipse restart. What is more, proposed earlier usage of the [DDMS tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446014/logcat-is-often-out-of-work#answer-4446028) give nothing and LogCat is still silent.

Could it be the bug of my concrete configuration? Or maybe there is common solutions (plugins or more stable framework version) for it?

It does not seem serious to develop application with Eclipse within the condition of permanent or regulag unavailable LogCat.

System details:

- Ubuntu 13.10 (64-bit)
- Eclipse v4.2.1
- ADT v22.0.5

Answer (score 2):

Go to DDMS and click on the device on the left in the list. Logcat should resume receiving messages from the device.

Comment: It works but result is unstable even in addition with physical device reconnect or Eclipse rebooting.