# How to keep LogCat working after clear all?

Tags: android, logcat

This bug from Google has been with us for years. Is there a work-around. Often when debugging logcat quits working after a **clear all**. I believe the emulator itself stops sending logging. I believe when one does a clear all is when this most often happens. Perhaps the debug monitor programmers close a stream and attempt to re-open, instead of just clear the screen. This one is a bug pain when you have lots of debugging to do. Is there any work-around?

@Lalit Poptani
Please read the below answer related to the one you believe to be a duplicate. Also, please read the one you assigned as a duplicate and tell where it answers this question. It does not. In fact, there are about four questions answered in the one referenced; but none of them answers this question. In fact, from what I can tell, this is a bug report to Google and there is no fix. It is possible, however, one could use Genymotion or another tool and reliably work with the logs. The problem is apparently a network communication flaw between Emulator and Monitor; so, another programmer could have written a better Monitor. Clearing a log is not a new capability of an IDE!!!!!

Comment: For now, I copy the entire output buffer into notepad++ and analyze there.

Comment: Windows 7 environment. I get the impression Google does not develop and test thoroughly on Windows and expects us to use Linux or Mac. Can't do that on this project due to bigco security.

Comment: BTW, there are LOTS of problems with AS. This is just an obvious and well known one. MANY, MANY, MANY time wasters. It doesn't seem Google either a) cares or b) has experienced programmers. Its a pain (and I've used well over a dozen IDE's in my career and I know. Its not the worst ever for sure, but no where near the best ever.)

Comment: In referenced questions, Preferred answer, @Paul, does not work. Wrong answer for this question.

Comment: In questions referenced as a duplicate, none of the other answers (shwiz, Falmarri, ikibotu, akbuildmaster, and Jimtronic) actually answer this question or add germane input to resolving this question.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse this problem is often seen.Switch to Android Studio for better Results.

Comment: I had hoped so but am using AS. Also used external monitor app. Sadly, problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using Android-Studio for debugging your application.
There will be a two windows available during debugging in android studio.

1. Android Monitor(alt+6): The section like Logcat/memory/CPU-GPU/Network sections are available
2. Debugging window(alt+5):  Where breakpoints and watches are shown

As per your question Logcat logs will be getting displayed/generated in monitor window when you are debugging your application.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a duplicate of:
[Logcat is often out of work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446014/logcat-is-often-out-of-work?rq=1)
?

@ikiboto says to run
    adb logcat -c

maybe that works reliably.

Not really. That answer makes no sense. That is not even how logcat -d works. It is not dynamic. Opening a file in update mode will never see any updates as there are none. Silly. https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file

Comment: Not really. That answer doesn't work reliably either. In testing.

Comment: That question is not a duplicate as there are several other possible issues with Using LogCat; but this question is about a specific bug in LogCat and/or the Emulator.